# Can't calibrate generic usb gamepad right thumb

Tags: controllers

I have a Chinese generic USB gamepad using the driver that Windows 10 came with because the included driver is 32bit and whenever I use x360ce on 64bit games (such as Sleeping Dogs), the game crashes

Now, the horizontal axis of right thumb is off, it consistently registers a force to the right, so in games where right thumb governs camera movement, the camera constantly moves horizontally. As you may imagine this is beyond annoying.

I tried the calibration feature of Windows 10 generic driver but for some reason it doesn't work only on that right thumb calibration (dpad and left thumb calibration works fine). It asked me to move the thumb to both extremes but doing that changes nothing (the thumb is still registering as tilted to the right).

I played around with X360CE's "dead zone" values, but got no success. Anything I can do at this point to fix it?

I'd prefer to calibrate it via software instead of cracking it open, but I will do it if there's no avenue left.

Comment: If you calibrated it in software and it's still registering as tilted to the right, it must be physically off-center. Aside from assigning a dead-zone, I doubt there's much you can do without cracking it open.

Comment: i know that there are programms in wich you can "fake" the controller mapping to apear like a legit 360Controller/ whatever you want. Changing input Values should be possible with those in a way that you calibrate the ground possitions. But its a long time ago that i used one of those programms sorry.

Comment: Will try to play with dead zone again, otherwise I may have to Crack it open